# Determine screen touch positions for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an eBook app. I am having some bitmaps to transit from left to right and right to left. I am not adding any fields to the screen. How to let the user to determine  the clicks on the screen using TouchEvent for bitmap transitions. I need to divide the screen in 3 parts such that each should having 120 pixel width for clicking bitmaps.

I am not able to implement FieldChangeListener as it is not support for app requirements.

I want to use the following code for to divide the screen. Is it the right code?

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {
            int x = message.getX(1);
            int y = message.getY(1);
            XYRect myArea = new XYRect();
            getExtent(myArea);
            myArea.setLocation(0, 0);
            if (myArea.contains(x, y)) {
                Dialog.alert("Click successful!");
            }
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Koushik in that case, I have another solution to your problem.

You can create add a HorizontalFieldManager to the screen which has HORIZONTAL_SCROLL added to it in the arguments

and, then keep adding your images to that HorizontalFieldManager. The images will be added directly one beside the other and you can swap across each images by simple touch events 
You need not actually write any specific code for the navigation

Let the images be BitmapFields

For better Look and feel you can make the focussed BitmapField to enlarge more

You can also add more to this, such as let each image occupy most of the screen and other images slighly visible so that it helps user identifying that there are images next to it
To occupy the whole screen you need to set the layout in the sublayout() method of the HorizontalFieldManager

Hope this will solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the above code wouldnt solve your requirements

if you are trying to actually flip through images using touch events, you can use the PictureScrollField but, I doubt if it works in storm

It must work well in storm2 since it uses version 6.0 OS

Using this you can actually flip through images from left to right and each image would be occupying the whole screen

If suppose the PictureScrollField is not compatible to your device then you can make use of the Field by creating a custom class and extending it with field

Please let me know if the problem is solved

Comment: Hi Dheeraj thanks for your reply..I need to develop it from 4.7, Storm version.